# How can I hide the ring under certain diacritic characters in an Arabic fonts?

Tags: font-design, font-forge, arabic

I'm looking for this ring in font forge to remove it or modify it but can't find it. Here is an example of these rings.

[image: example for rings]

They are supposed to read like this:

[image: what they should look like]

However, I merged the two fonts above to yield the following result:

[image: what they should look like]

I'd like to pick specific diacritics to replace, but I do not know how.

Comment: What are these rings? How do you add them when typing text, is it like an accented letter or are they a separate character?

Comment: The rings appear under (or sometimes above) diacritic marks. The marks are their own character and are normally used above (or below) letters. If you type the accent without a preceding letter, it will appear with a ring. To add them while typing (with an arabic keyboard) you press shift+[the diacritic that you want].